# Выбрать максимальное значение столбца из таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю так

```
$client = $_POST['client'];
$loginMax = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(number) FROM product WHERE login = 
$client") or die(mysqli_error($link));
var_dump ($loginMax);
```

выдает ошибку

```
Unknown column 'spoon' in 'where clause'
```

$client = 'spoon';

Таблица имеет вид

```
login|number
spoon| 1
spoon| 1
spoon| 3
```

Comment: Строки в кавычки следует заключать.

Comment: И как вы думаете `login = spoon` это что?

Answer (score -2):

```
$client = $_POST['client'];    
$loginMax = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(number) FROM product WHERE login = '" . $client . "'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
var_dump ($loginMax);
```

Так будет работать. Но я уверен, что практически все скажут что так делать нельзя. Надо использовать параметризированные запросы.

Comment: А еще надо результаты запроса __фетчить__.